# Using REGEXEXTRACT to retrieve specific content from two separate rows in the same column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regexextract

[I Included a Google Sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gczyH4RDSXxJrc7wPADj4UZmnUWQMoxc9AdN_RK8Qfs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3, "19..")
```

To me, it would seem as if this would check both cells for any date starting with `19` and extract that into the cell

But, it doesn't work out.

Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A3, "19..")`
> To me, it would seem as if this would check both cells for any date starting with "19" and extract that into the cell.

As you found out it does not work that way.

`REGEXEXTRACT` works per row.
So you would need `=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"#(.*)")`
On top of that, you would have to use the above formula on every row where an RC number is found.

---

### **How to insert an empty row, every other row.**

**The use of advanced formulas.**
Instead you can use advanced formulas to achieve the same results for all rows (present and future).

You will have to create -anywhere in your sheet- a helper column using the formula

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A11,"#(.*)"))), "where Col1 is not null")
```

You will then need to clear all cells in range `D2:D` and apply the following on cell `D2`

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORT(F2:F,SORT(ROW(F2:F),MOD(ROW(F2:F),2),1),1),COUNTA(F2:F)*2,1)
```

[image: Insert an empty row every other row]

Using the same technique you can have the `Year` column in just one go.

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [`MOD`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093497)
- [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
- [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)